# Alternatives to setTimeout after an Ajax callback

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, settimeout

I find myself doing this a lot:

```
window.onload = function(){

   $.get("http://example.com/example.html", function(data) {
       $('#contentHere').html(data);

       setTimeout("javaScriptClass.init()", 200);
   });

}
```

But setTimeout seems a bit hacky (and 200ms is already over three times the attention span of the average user :).  What's the best alternative?

**EDIT**

javaScriptClass.init() acts on DOM objects from what is loaded in the ajax call

Comment: Why do you have a delay at all?

Comment: @Nick!  javaScriptClass.init() acts on DOM objects from what is loaded in the ajax call

Comment: They'll be loaded immediately after the line before with the `.html()` call, it's a synchronous operation.

Comment: @Nick I'm toggling back and forth between `javaScriptClass.init()` and `setTimeout("javaScriptClass.init()", 200);` and getting different results.  With the delay it works and without it doesn't. Should I reframe the question then?

Comment: Are you loading images in the content, and those are needed? That's the only scenario I can picture not being completely synchronous here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there's some confusion here about the load, you can just do this:

```
window.onload = function(){    
   $.get("http://example.com/example.html", function(data) {
       $('#contentHere').html(data);
       javaScriptClass.init();
   });    
}
```

After the `$('#contentHere').html(data);` the DOM elements will be there ready to use.  Also take a look at [`.load()`](http://api.jquery.com/load-event/) for attachment (in case *other* `onload` handlers may need to attach), like this:

```
$(window).load(function(){    
   $.get("http://example.com/example.html", function(data) {
       $('#contentHere').html(data);
       javaScriptClass.init();
   });    
});
```

Though, unless you're waiting on images, this can be called in a `document.ready` handler and fire sooner, resulting in a better user experience.

Comment: Thanks Nick.  I'm befuddled but this is obviously the right answer.